# WiFi no longer connects (specific network only)

Tags: network, macos, wifi, internet

I can no longer connect to a specific public user+pass protected network from my 2017 MBP 15″.

Same network with same auth is accessible from my iPhone and Android tablet.

Network used to be accessible with these details from MacOS. I've tried removing the network, rebooting, readding.

What else can I try? - Is there a global cache somewhere? - Should I try editing my MAC Address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually installing the certificate fixed my issue.